# How to add dynamic days to Date using Date_Add function in BigQuery

Tags: sql, function, date, dynamic, google-bigquery

I want to add a dynamic number of days to Date but the existing Date_Add function in BigQuery is not allowing me to replace interval integer with a column name. Is there another function or workaround to achieve this?

Example of what I'd want to achieve using the Date_Add function. This is throwing me an error.

```
Date_Add(due_date, interval dynamic_col_nme day)
```

If due_date = 6/10/2019 and dynamic_col_nme = 5 then the expected result is 6/15/2019.

Comment: provide [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easy to understand your problem and help you. obviously just saying that your query actually works (as already done in first answer) does not help a lot if at all

Answer (score 2):

You use `date_add()`:

```
select date_add(due_date, interval dynamic_col_nme day)
```

This works fine when I try it in Standard SQL:

```
select date_add(dte, interval n day)
from (select current_date as dte, 5 as n union all
      SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 10
     ) x
```

Comment: I am currently pulling dynamic_col_nme from a table so it will change dynamically for each record and is not always defined as a value of 5.

Comment: For example here is my query: select due_date, DATE_ADD(due_date, interval dynamic_col_nme day) as report_date
from dataset.view_name

Comment: When I ran this query I got an error that said: Interval value must be coercible to INT64 type

Comment: Oh I think I found a solution. It worked when I cast dynamic_col_nme as Int64. Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question!

Comment: @ck87 . . . This works in Standard SQL.  I tried it before posting it.  The value `n` differs on the two rows.